# how do I get box-sizing working when using zurb foundation?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Experimenting with zurbs foundation, I've found two columns set to sit next to each other in a row actually "staircased". ie, on of them ended up sitting under the other.

At this point, I'm just using two sass files:  _foundation-global.scss and  _grid.scss

I found the problem to be within the grid defaults: foundations default padding for the boxes extended the width of the columnar boxes. As a result, the sum width extended beyond the .row.

This confuses me: foundations grid documentation says this:

"Foundation uses box-sizing: border-box so that borders and padding do not affect the overall width of the columns, making the math dead-simple"

Contrary to this, I found that the boxes were not set to box-sizing: border-box.

So, of course I included new rules in a new stylesheet, setting divs, articles and sections to border-box.

However, I then discovered that this setting didn't help in firefox. Turns out firefox doesn't support this property. Chrome seems to. I haven't tested across other browsers yet.

So, whats up with this? Surely foundation should support firefox, and I'm just missing something.

Comment: I think for firefox is: `-moz-box-sizing`

Answer (score 1):

Firefox still requires prefixes at this point in time:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Since Foundation is built on top of Compass, you can just use the `box-sizing` mixin from Compass to take care of all of the prefixes for you:

```
@import 'compass/css3/box-sizing';

.foo {
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

Comment: Is this mixin included as part of foundation?

The docs for foundation give the impression that foundation can be used without being forced to use compass.

Comment: No, it is part of Compass.  http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/.  Not sure why you don't want to use Compass, but you could easily create your own mixin that does basically the same thing.

Comment: I'm not interesting in using compass or anything that requires it because the documentation for it is so poor.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem the other day. In order for box-sizing to be automatically applied, you have to put your columns inside a div with the `row` class.

But most importantly, and this is what I was missing... you also need apply the class `columns` to your column divs (E.G. `class="large-6 columns`) along with the number class

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">...</div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the following code to your CSS fixes the box sizing issues in older versions of Firefox.

```
.row,
[class*="block-grid-"]
{
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

*Tested on Firefox 16.0.2 on Windows 7*